# SSIS ExecutePackageTask is not avavailbe in SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016

I am writing the code to read the SSIS Package from SSISDB Catalog in SQL Server 2016. In one of the requirement, I need to read the `ExecutePackage` task and get the package name from it.

As per Microsoft Doc (See link  [ExecutePackageTaskClass Class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.executepackagetask.executepackagetaskclass(v=sql.110).aspx) ) I need to add `Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecPackageTaskWrap.dll` in my project but I am not able to find it in my SQL Server 2016 Program folder.

Please suggest.

Comment: It is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in the GAC (global assembly cache)

In the solution, right-click on the project. Click on add reference. then write the following path:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecPackageTaskWrap\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecPackageTaskWrap.dll
```

Comment: Hi Hadi, It is not there. I searched there (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL) and SQL Server folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Tasks)  both before posting my question. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find it in folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ExecPackageTaskWrap